# "add widget" button starts app instead of updating widget

Tags: android, widget

I have a widget with configure activity.

When app is not launched and i'm adding widget through widgets menu - "add widget" button works fine.

When app is launched, but tabbed (can be found in launched apps in square button menu) add button calls MainActivity.

Here is the code of add button click:

```
View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("ACTIVITY mOnClickListener");
        //final Context context = RatesWidgetConfigureActivity.this;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ConfigData.WIDGET_SHARED_PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        editor.putString("widget_currency_1", spCurrencyFirst.getSelectedItem().toString());
        editor.putString("widget_currency_2", spCurrencySecond.getSelectedItem().toString());
        editor.putString("widget_currency_3", spCurrencyThird.getSelectedItem().toString());
        editor.commit();

        // It is the responsibility of the configuration activity to update the app widget

        InAppProperties.getInstance().LoadingRates = true;
        RatesWidget.isRefresh = true;


        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        RatesWidget.updateAppWidget(getApplicationContext(), appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);


        // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
        Intent resultValue = new Intent();
        resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
        finish();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
add that code in after finish():

```
 Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
```